# Edit and append items to nested list - Python 2.7

Tags: list, python-2.7, nested, list-comprehension

I'm struggling folks. I have searched this forum and Google but can't find a simple answer that I can understand.

I have a nested list "plot" it would have hundreds of sublists all in the format of this sample:

plot = [['A', 21.09], ['A', 10.00], ['A', 20.99], ['B', 58.50], ['B', 17.69]]

I need to change the items in the sublists and store them in a new list "plotlists". These are the changes I need to make:

[?][0] (all first sublist items) if they are 'A' change to 0 if they are 'B' change to 1 
[?][1] (2nd items) no change
[?][2] (3rd - new items) if [?][0] is 'A' then this item = -1 else it is [?][1] * 1.2

I have tried many ways to achieve this but the best I can get is a right mess of code that produces 3 new lists i.e.

Here is a minimal sample:

```
plot = [['A', 21.09], ['A', 10.00], ['A', 20.99], ['B', 58.50], ['B', 17.69]]
plot0 = []
plot1 = []
plot2 = []
for i in plot:
    plot0.append(i[0])
    plot1.append(i[1])

for i in plot0:
    if i == 'A':
        plot0.append(0)
    elif 1 == 'B':
        plot0.append(1)

for i in plot0:
    if i == 'A':
        plot2.append(-1)
    elif i == 'B':
        plot2.append(1.2)
```

Result:

```
plot0 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
plot1 = [21.09, 10.00, 29.99, 58.50, 17.69]
plot2 = [-1, -1, -1, 1.2, 1.2]
```

Please can anyone show me ow to write this as a list comprehension that produces a result like this:

```
plotlists = [[0, 21.09, -1][0, 10.00, -1][0, 29.99, -1][1, 58.50, 70.56][1, 17.69, 21.23]]
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service; where is your attempt, and precisely what is wrong with it? Provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that recreates the issue.

Comment: This is the best I can do so far: plot = [['A', 21.09], ['A', 10.00], ['A', 20.99], ['B', 58.50], ['B', 17.69]]
plot0 = []
plot1 = []
plot2 = []
for i in plot:
    plot0.append(i[0])
    plot1.append(i[1])

for i in plot0:
    if i == 'A':
        plot0.append(0)
    elif 1 == 'B':
        plot0.append(1)

for i in plot0:
    if i == 'A':
        plot2.append(-1)
    elif i == 'B':
        plot2.append(1.2)

Comment: **Edit the question.** Whitespace is important in Python, it is unreadable in a comment.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Well, it doesn't produce the nested list the I am trying to get. Can't remember how I got the last bit to do the multiply, though.

Comment: But your "wrong result" is only a `zip` away from what you say you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather long list comprehension but it'll work:

```
new_list = [[0 if sublist[0] is 'A' else 1, sublist[1], -1 if sublist[0] is 'A' else 1.2*sublist[1]] for sublist in plot]
```

Update: Auto increment counter

```
new_list = [[i, 0 if sublist[0] is 'A' else 1, sublist[1], -1 if sublist[0] is 'A' else 1.2*sublist[1]] for i, sublist in zip(xrange(0, len(plot)), plot)]
```

Comment: It certainly works. Thanks. And it doesn't seem too long to me!

Comment: Something I forgot. I need to have an auto increment counter as the first item in each nested list. Whatever I try gives errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks. So simple but I couldn't figure it out.